# Is it possible to remove an item from a listbox populated with a database?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Before i ask "How to remove an item from a listbox populated with a database"

Is it possible to remove an item from a listbox populated with a database?

if it is possible, my code is not working:

```
Dim str As String
            Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(ListBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
            str = CStr(drv.Row.Item("PName"))
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem(str))
```

**This is how i populate my lsitbox**

```
 'Populate the ListBox with personnelName from personnel '
    Try
        connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Nikko Jaze Fabellon\Documents\ASRASIM.accdb")
        connection.Open()
        ds = New DataSet
        tables = ds.Tables
        dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [FirstName],[LastName] from [Personnel] where [Status] = 'Activated' ", connection)
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Personnel")
        Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
        With personnelList
            .DataSource = ds.Tables("Personnel")
            .DisplayMember = "FirstName"
            .ValueMember = "LastName"
            .SelectedIndex = 0
        End With

        connection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

or if it is not possible, i need advice to think of another way.

Comment: How do you populate it? If its bound, you need to remove the item from your backing source. Or `ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)` if its not bound.

Comment: i updated my codes, can u help me?